# How can I return information which was found by threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having the following situation:

- about 10 threads which crawl the web for images
- all found images must somehow be returned to 10 other threads (for analyzing)

As said, I want to **process the images** at the same time with the 10 **other threads**.

Currently I have this **Singleton** implementation of an own list:

```
public class ImageList extends Observable implements Iterable<Image> {
    private final BlockingQueue<Image> images = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Image>();

    private static class InstanceHolder {
        public static ImageList instance = new ImageList();
    }

    public static ImageList getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.instance;
    }

    private ImageList() {

    }

    public synchronized void execute(Image job) throws InterruptedException {
        images.put(job);

        new Thread(job).start();

        System.out.println("notify observers");
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();

        System.out.println(this.countObservers());
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Image> iterator() {
        return images.iterator();
    }
}
```

And as soon as an image is found, I execute `ImageList.execute(image)`, but I do not like this solution, because there is **no upper bound** to the parallel processes (it might become thousands).

Another idea I had:

- pass an **additional list** `imagesFound` to all my crawlers, let them add all images into that list
- start 5 threads in the Main class which constantly check for new elements in `imagesFound` and process them

However, I do not like this solution either, because passing an array which is **not really needed** by the thread (but just used to pass back found data) **seems wrong** to me. It might become 20 different lists if I want to search for 20 different informations on a website.

So, how do you usually implement the return of data from threads (in my case: especially if this data itself shall be processed by other threads).

Comment: I like the general queue solution. If the real problem is the upper bound, consider a thread pool (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). Also, here's the first in a two part article that may help: http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/java-concurrency-queue-processing-part-1/232700457.

Comment: That's the basic producer-consumer pattern - if you search on SO for it, you'll find more than enough on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a thread pool? Check out [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

- You can set the number of worker threads.
- It automatically encapsulates a thread-safe work queue.

Example:

```
class Task implements Callable<Object> {

    private Image job;

    public Task(Image job) {
       this.job = job;
    }

    public Object call() {
        // crawl
        return result;
    }
}
```

...

```
// Initialize thread pool
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

// every time you get a new job
Future<Object> result = exec.submit(new Task(job));

// when you want to collect the result
Object obj = result.get();
```

Comment: Ah I already saw that class and also thought about using it, but somehow I got stuck in how to really implement it, so I posted the question more generally. Maybe you can give me a hint? Architecture is like this: A `Main` class starts 5 `Crawler` threads. Where do I have to put the executor service (probably in `Main`?) and how can I return all found images to it? (same problem somehow)

Comment: Ah, when I figured out, I could put it into the already existing Singleton class, it was really easy :) Awesome.